# float right and float left in absolute container - IE7 Expands to 100% width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to float left and float right in an absolute container..It works fine in chrome,ff
expected behaviour is that of chrome..to just have the width of the children not the entire width.

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='floatLeft'>float left </div>
    <div class='floatRight'>float right </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    background-color: orange;
    position:absolute;
}
.floatLeft{
    float:left;
    background-color: green;
}
.floatRight{
    float:right;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

In IE and Chrome[image: In Chrome]

Comment: And what happens when you set a width to your container?

Comment: It works fine with width..but in an absolute container..I cannot decide the width

Comment: block elements got 100% as default. You must set a width to the element.

Comment: not when it is absolute..check what it looks like in chrome/ff

Comment: IE7 ?? really? that is awful..

Comment: I tried to test this with http://jsfiddle.net/5wn2v/, except it doesn't even seem to run on IE7/8. But if you don't believe that block elements default to 100%, read this: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score -1):

That's due to IE7 having been a crappy browser when it comes to implementation of the Visual Formatting Model as specified by the W3C. Whereas absolutely positioned block elements should shrink-wrap to fit their contents, IE7 let them stretch to the maximum available width, even the canvas width, if they contained a pair of L- en R-floated elements.

I would suggest to not code for IE7 anymore. Their owners have to actively stop Windows Update from updating it to 8. At every Update, even to this day. And if you would be concerned about higher IE versions in Compatibility Mode/View, there are easy ways to force them into their natural, own mode when used to visit your site.

Also, it is very rarely used anymore. I even heard it has left the building yesterday. :-)